# How to start a program through putty, then disconnect but program keeps running on remote Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, telnet

I will be running some batch process on Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 12 machines. I can log in using putty, run the command. The process will run for a day or two. There is a chance the putty will get disconnected. However I need the program keep running on the remote Ubuntu machine. Is it possible?

Like Windows RDP, log in to a machine, start some app, disconnect, come back later, app is still running. Similar experience in Ubuntu, how can I get? Thank you.

Thanks/.

Comment: If you are running `telnet`, you're in BIG trouble. Please use `ssh`!

Comment: @DeerHunter I don't believe it's possible to get into an EC2 instance with `telnet`, but i can't explain why the question includes it.

Comment: why not install cron jobs on your 12 machines and let cron run your commands for you?

Comment: @RedCricket That seems like an awfully roundabout way of just executing something in the background

Comment: @Robbie how so? opening up putty or a windows `C:\>` and then executing putty then login in to 12 different boxes and running a command seem far more "roundabout" then have a simple cron job on each of the boxes.   I guess to some people setting up a cronjob is difficult. To each his own I guess.

Comment: In addition to `screen`, `tmux`, or `dtach`, there are also `nohup` and `batch` for totally non-interactive jobs. It sounds a bit like you should be submitting these via `batch` perhaps …

Comment: @RedCricket If each job only needs to be run once, why would you use a service designed to run services more than once? Perhaps you're assuming that the job does need to be run more than once, but i see no reason to assume that. If the job only should be run once, it's less work to log into each box and run the job rather than log onto each box and add a cron job

Answer (score 6):

Screen. You will probably need to install it with `apt-get install screen` or similar, but once you have it, it's quite straight forward. Use `screen` to start it, and you will be given a `bash` or `sh` shell, use that to run your batch job, then use Ctrl+A followed by Ctrl+D to detach from the session. You may then log out, and can reattach at any time using `screen -r`. See `man screen` for more information. You could also simply fork the job to the background with an ampersand, `./job.sh &`, but you will not be able to reattach to it at some later point in time.

Comment: Tmux is far more flexible than screen IMHO, but they both get the job done.

Comment: I'll have to check that out

Comment: By the way, Screen is already installed on the default Amazon EC2 AMI. They must realize it's useful ;)

Answer (score 6):

use nohup and & with your command / batch process. RUn you script or command like below

```
  nohup command &
```

even your putty session disconnect your command will continue to run in background.